# Бот для telegram на aiogram3. Как собрать данные после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: aiogram-3.x

У меня есть inline кнопка в боте искать город и есть хендлер который обрабатывает нажатия по этой кнопке. Как мне прописать чтоб после нажатия на кнопку сообщение менялось на "Введите город:" и бот ожидал ввода города пользователем после чего сохранял в переменную.

Пробовал делать FSM но мне надо как-то связать его чтоб он выполнялся сразу же после того как пользователь нажмет на кнопку.